# Secure Scoped Bookmark in plain C

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, entitlements

I am trying to create an manage security scoped bookmarks but need to use only plain C, that is using Objective-C in a plain C file.

Is it even doable or should I just give up?

Any advices?
Can I call Obj-C function inside C function and keeping the file as .c?

Thank you in advance all, 
Nikolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't imagine why you'd want to use only `C` when you have support for `Objective-C` available. But if you really want to do it, then a valid approach is to use the `CoreFoundation` support for `NSURL` and memory management.

All URL `CoreFoundation` functions can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/1666471-cfurl).

Regarding the memory management, you might be interested in the `CFRetain`/`CFRelease` functions, which are very well described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000127i).

Basically if `C` is all you want, then `CoreFoundation` is a good start, as it has support for many of the `Cocoa`/`CocoaTouch` types.

Comment: I am using a 3rd party programming environment for development, that has no support for Ocbjective-C. So, I am trying the long way around for things like that.
Thank you for the info, I will look into it.
Nik

Comment: @NikolasKon then `CoreFoundation` is the framework you need. If your development environment allows to link agains it, ofcourse :)

Comment: as I understand i should now use the `CoreFoundation`'s `CFURLCreateBookmarkData` **instead** of `bookmarkDataWithOptions` that is referred at the [Security-Scoped Bookmarks and Persistent Resource Access](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW16). 
I haven't tried it yet, but it much clearer now, you really helped me a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is doable, but it is basically the same as doing the work the compiler otherwise would do for you. And you cannot use ARC.

I have found the best documentation to be in the header files in the `objc` include folder.

E.g. look up the variants of `objc_msgSend` available in `#include <objc/message.h`